# jQuery- Button not working after loading content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using **Codeigniter** and having trouble on my `button` after I load my page using `load` function on `jQuery`.

`reg_form.php` loads first, then after saving data, it will load the `page-content` class to see the list of data but when I'm trying to go to `reg_form.php` again using the `button`, nothing happens.

`JS` is not working on the current loaded page

**reg_form.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page-content">
      <label>Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <button id="save"></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**reg_list.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page-content">
      <button id="reg_form"></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**reg.js**

```
$('#reg_form').click(function(){
    $(".page-content").load('reg_form');
});

$('#save').click(function(){
  var name = $('#ame').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"gatepass/save",
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
      name:name
    },
    success:function(data){
      $(".page-content").load('reg_list');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: use event delegation like `$(document).on('click','#save',function(){`

Comment: Use delegate, http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: There is no `.page-container` in the HTML... And why are you using `.load()` (which is a shorthand for an ajax request) in an ajax request `success` callback? You don't even use the `data` returned. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned solution.

```
$(document).on('click','#reg_form',function(){
    $(".page-content").load('reg_form');
});

$(document).on('click','#save',function(){
  var name = $('#ame').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"gatepass/save",
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
      name:name
    },
    success:function(data){
      $(".page-container").load('reg_list');
    }
  });
});
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs and events in the content that you add after the DOM loads should be defined using the `.on()` function as shown below use of `.delegate()` has been discontinued:

```
$(document).on(events,selector,data,eventhandler);
```

If for example you add the button below into the div after DOM loads and you want the button to say 'You clicked me' when clicked, the code would be:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#justClickMe', function(e) {
        alert('You clicked me');
    })

    $('#content').append('<button id="justClickMe">Just Click Me</button>');
});
```

```html
<div id="content"><h3>New Content</h3></div>
```